# Possible ways of injecting a wcf client with structuremap

Tags: c#, wcf, structuremap

I would like to use structuremap to inject a wcf client but I also would like that this client reads the endpoint and binding configurations from the config.
I tried the following:

```
For<IServiceClient>().LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()).Use<ServiceClient>().
            Ctor<string>("endpointConfigurationName").Is("WsHttpBinding_IService");
```

But this will result in the error:

> StructureMap Exception Code:  205\nMissing requested Instance property \"remoteAddress\" for InstanceKey \"e50e036b-9d71-47de-8ac2-d53a641e9be8\"

When I pass the remoteAddress it work's like expected:

```
 For<IServiceClient>().LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()).Use<ServiceClient>()
           .Ctor<string>("endpointConfigurationName").Is("WsHttpBinding_IService")
           .Ctor<string>("remoteAddress").Is("https://myurl/Service.svc");
```

I don't understand why the first constructor overload does not read the endpoint address from the config?
The config looks like this:

>

```
 <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myurl/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="IService" name="WsHttpBinding_IService" />
 </client>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first overload does probably read the endpoint address, but StructureMap never calls this first overload, but always calls the most greedy constructor. Prefer using the `Use` method and supply a factory delegate:

```
For<IService>()
  .LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle())
  .Use(() => new ServiceClient("WsHttpBinding_IService"))
```

This forces the use of the right constructor for this generated class. Perhaps it's even better to hide that class behind a proxy. This way to can hide [the annoying quirks](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html) of WCF from your application. And for types that you create yourself, [prevent having multiple constructors](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: Steven, your answer is awesome. it saves me many times. I wonder if you correct me in here as well ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546490/how-to-do-unit-test-a-service-which-has-wcf-client-called